# SSIS: Only Update DB not entire list

Tags: sql, sharepoint, ssis, insert-update

i have a really simple question what is one of the ways to only fill a DB with data that is not already in the Table ?

I am currently trying to implement a Project which gets data from a SharePoint List and stores it in a Table on my DataWarehouse, and i had to realise that if run more than once, it keeps filling the table with data it already has!

[image: SSIS: SharePoint list to Ole DB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between your source and your destination, you want to evaluate whether there is a match in the destination (and possibly determine whether there have been changes between the values).

The SSIS tool you're looking for is the [Lookup Transformation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx). More generally speaking, you're performing an incremental load and Andy Leonard has a great series called the [Stairway to Integration Services](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) that covers how to handle this at a basic to complex level based on your needs.

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot,
I am having some Trouble finding the Lookup Transformation though,
It seems as though it's nowhere to be found  ?
any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In plain english, you want a query like this:

```
insert into mytable
(fields)
select values
where they are not already in the table
```

There are several ways to do this.  Here are a couple

```
where (select count(*)
from mytable
where whatever) = 0

where not exists
(subquery goes here)

where somefield in
(select somefield from staging_table
except 
select somefield from mytable)
```

Comment: do i have to use a Caml query in SSIS, or is this even doable in SSIS? thanks for the Answer

Comment: You can do it in a stored procedure and make that sp part of your package.