# Filter Values against DB Table - SSIS

Tags: sql, filter, ssis

I am currently trying to filter out data that Comes from a SharePoint List Source against the Table it is filling (see Picture below) 
the Problem is  don't know what Tools can really be used to do this,
It's a Problem for me because instead of only adding the rows to the Table i am filling which aren't already there, it keeps filling it with all the Values

Does anybody know how this is done ?
Thanks a lot in advance

[image: SSIS Project View]

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSIS: Only Update DB not entire list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814516/ssis-only-update-db-not-entire-list)

Comment: Probably, but that wasn't all that good explained

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to add to the target table the records that are not yet there.

You could use a lookup component for this. Set the "rows with no matching" handler to "Redirect to no match output", and configure the target table as connection. Then use the "No Match Output" only, ignoring the "Match Output". And send the records from the "No Match Output" to the target.

In spite of its name, the "Lookup" component can be used to filter data in many cases.